# Не работает Bloom на камере в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, камера

Подключаю к главной камере стандартный скрипт Bloom, и ничего не происходит, скрипт активный, переменные меняю, пусто, что есть скрипт, что его нет. Объекты не отсвечивают. Скачал новый пак Post Processing в котором так же содержится Bloom, который подключаю к камере, но результат все тот же. Возможно, что не понимаю, как должен работать, или чего то не хватает.

Answer (score 1):

включи HDR на камере на которую вешаешь скрипт блума. Без этого блум работать не будет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]